# refactor a ruby method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, refactoring

I seem to be writing quite a few methods with the following pattern and it seems like there should be a better way.  Is there a one-liner for this or a better practice?

```
def combine_roster(roster)
  rstr = []
  roster.each do |r|
    rstr << r.user
  end
  rstr
end
```

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-collect   (AKA map)

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Phrogz - nice.  Didn't know that existed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use the map command. Here is the short hand version for what you are trying to do:

```
roster.map(&:user) # if roster = [r1, r2, r3] then the output will be [r1.user, r2.user, r3.user]
```

You can read more about the map function in the Ruby Array API: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-map